# Best way to send an ArrayList<String[]> over TCP in Java?

Tags: java, networking, tcp, client

I'm writing a client/server application in Java and I'm using TCP to transfer data which I'm storing in an ArrayList (i.e. An ArrayList of arrays of Strings).

What is the best way to transfer that data from one to the other? Should I make one long string and use a PrintWriter's println() or is there a better way?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a bit to skaffman's answer:

```
OutputStream socketStream = ... 
GZIPOutputStream objectOutput = new GZIPOutputStream(new ObjectOutputStream(socketStream));
objectOutput.writeObject(myDataList);
```

And on the client:

```
InputStream socketStream = ...
ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(socketStream));
ArrayList<type> a = objectInput.readObject();
```

Comment: I'd avoid the GZIP stuff, though, unless you're on a low-bandwidth network and you have CPU cycles to burn.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming both client and server and written in Java, and assuming you're stick with raw sockets, rather than a higher-level remoting framework:

```
OutputStream socketStream = ... 
ObjectOutput objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socketStream);
objectOutput.writeObject(myDataList);
```

Similarly, use `ObjectInputStream` at the receiving end.

Should work nicely, as long as everything inside the list implements `java.io.Serializable`.

Comment: +1 surely the *first* choice for a Java client/server solution

Comment: Thanks, I'll look in to that, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the JSON framework.  See [json.org](http://json.org)  `JSON = Javascript Object Notation`.  Even though the name suggests the use of Javascript, the json.jar is a good serialization/deserialization tool.

Comment: ah I've used JSON with Javascript before, might be a good choice thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many people would use a web service framework for this, such as [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org). You could also go one level down to JAXB or XML Beans.

Comment: Ah interesting, I'll take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/). You could just make up your own format for such a simple case, though. Personally I favour [bencoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode). The minimum effort (and least bug-prone) solution here is Serialization, though.

Comment: Thanks I'll research them both!